# Adding iMessage style reaction bubble when using contextMenu in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu

I'm trying to mimic the interactions with a chat message as seen in iMessage, Instagram, and WhatsApp.
[image]

I can build the views and the context menu, but I cannot get them to work together effectively.

In this code block, I'm using the contextMenu preview to stack the reaction bubble on top of the message, but the message bubble jerks and there is an undesirable white background behind the whole view.

```
  var body: some View {
        MessageView
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    // do copy
                }) {
                    Text("Copy Message")
                    Image(systemName: "doc")
                }
            } preview: {
                VStack {
                    ReactionsView
                    MessageView
                }
            }
    }
    
    var MessageView : some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
    
    var ReactionsView : some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray5))
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                .clipped()
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Image(systemName: "hands.clap.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

If I change the preview block to use an overlay, I get the same jerk of the view, but the overlay then disappears.

```
    var body: some View {
        MessageView
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    // do copy
                }) {
                    Text("Copy Message")
                    Image(systemName: "doc")
                }
            } preview: {
                MessageView
                    .overlay {
                        ReactionsView
                            .offset(y: -50)
                    }
            }
    }
```

[image]

I've tried several other variations with similar results. How can I make this work so it looks good and feels like these other apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the background of your preview. E.g. test this:

```
                    preview: {
                        VStack {
                            ReactionsView
                            MessageView
                        }.background(Color.gray)
                    }
```

Unfortunately `Color.clear` or `.clear` don't achieve the desired effect, so it's not quite as easy as that. However, if you don't mind a bit of experimentation you may be able to mimic the color and blur (using a [material](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material)) to match that applied to the main view behind your context menu.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it doesn't feel production worthy. I may need to build a custom solution since it doesn't seem there is a concise out of the box way to achieve this effect.